# how do you write the derived ("/ ") access modifier into cpp code?

Tags: c++, uml, software-design, class-diagram

Is there any correct way  to write the following  UML diagram in to c++ ?

The UML class diagram :

[image: UML class diagram]

If so , how to write in c++ from the given diagram ?
I was confuse in the "/" part ( " derived access modifier " ).

fyi : i am new to UML diagrams

Comment: what do you think /  means? and, btw, uml is a not bad way of documenting existing code but a terrible way of designing new code.

Comment: Given that `salary` _"... is produced or computed from other information..."_ ([UML Derived Property](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/derived-property.html)).  There is no information in the diagram as to what `salary` is derived from.  I would suggest it's a get property with perhaps the value being cached if it's expensive to compute.

Comment: @RichardCritten why not posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Of course, hacking code from the keyboard is more efficient. To get a dump of code.

Comment: @Christophe because the question was missing information - I had voted to close as "needs more information".

Answer (score 1):

The "/" means the attribute is derived. This in turn means it comes from "higher spheres" which means e.g. from a general class or from some calculation using other attributes. P. 17 of UML 2.5 says

> Attributes: each specified by its name, type, and multiplicity, and any additional properties such as {readOnly}. If no multiplicity is listed, it defaults to 1..1. This is followed by a textual description of the purpose and meaning of the attribute. If an attribute is derived, the name will be preceded by a forward slash. Where an attribute is derived, the logic of the derivation is in most cases shown using OCL.

Since the shown diagram does not tell the derivation logic you can't tell anything about it. For the time being implement a simple attribute or leave it from its parent. You will have to get the rules to make it a correct implementation before ending the coding.

Comment: Has UML’s "derived" something to do with c++’s derived (aka uml specialization/inheritance) ? I naively thought it was an attribute that can be determined from other properties

Comment: @Christophe I don't know c++ very well, but UML's derived attributes are what the name says: derived (by some rules). It can be any derivation like `salary`is `yearsOfServive * 1000 + 100000` (haha)

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your statement about “higher spheres”. Indeed, there are a number of places where salary of a professor is driven by a salary grid by year of service (e.g. https://www.ugent.be/en/work/talent/welcoming-new-staff/salaryscales/zapeas1.htm or https://tea.texas.gov/texas-educators/salary-and-service-record/minimum-salary-schedule/2022-2023-minimum-salary-schedule). I can imagine some places on earth where they’d add a bonus dependent on the number of classes ;-)

Comment: @Christophe Yes, the reading is a bit misleading. I'll try to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal mapping from UML to C++, because there are many ways to implement a design intent.

In the case of the derived attribute, there are three frequently used strategies:

- use a getter that derives (computes) the value when it is needed:

  ```
  class Professor {
  public: 
      …
      int getSalary() const {
         // some computation, e.g:
         return salaryScale(yearsOfService)+numberOfClasses*CLASS_BONUS;
      }
      …
   };
  ```
- use an attribute, and update it with the computation, every-time a parameter changes. This is however only reliable if the computation depends only on private members and is difficult to maintain:

  ```
  class Professor {
  private:
      int salary;
      …
  public: 
      …

      int getSalary() const {
         return salary; 
      }
      void setYearsOfService(int n)
          yearsOfService=n;
         // update:
         salary =  salaryScale(yearsOfService);
         // better put the calculation in a private function, to not repeat formula multiple times
      }
      …
   };
  ```
- use a smart getter, that caches the value in a private salary attribute, but computes it only when needed. The idea is to have a „dirty“ flag that is set whenenver the state of the object changes, and if the getter is called and dirty flag is set, recompute the value. Be aware however that this majes it more difficult to maintain. Moreover, if the derivation depends on associated objects, you‘d need to consider the observer pattern. So I‘d advise to use this approach as last resort, in case of heavy computations.

By the way, `/` doesn’t say anything about visibility (I just assumed public in my example), whereas `+`, `-`, `#` refer to `public`, `private`, `protected` in C++, and UML‘s `~` package visibility has no equivalent in c++.